# Python で可変長引数で渡された引数の中で、末尾の引数の値を返すには？

Tags: python

自力でこれになりましたが、できませんでした。
最善は尽くしました。ヒントでもいいので、教えてください。

```
def get_tail(*args):
    print(*args[-1])
get_tail(4,3,5,5,3)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。解決できました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def get_tail(*args):
    return args[-1] if args else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_cases = [
        [4,3,5,5,3],
        [4],
        []
    ]

    for tc in test_cases:
        print(get_tail(*tc))

#
3
4
None
```